# Increase first load speed in laravel project

Tags: laravel

i am new in laravel. I did worked in codeigniter for more than 40 projects but did not faced any load issue. Now in new project we are working in laravel, where i just setup and checked laravel then it founds that it load some time in first load. Once load then it works ok, but each time when new session is start after open browser then it takes some time approx 2 seconds evenif there is simple hello page.  Any suggestion to improve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- check the console for any errors , maybe there is a loop not closed.
2- second : you can install some debugging packages like

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: I did not created any my own code. I just installed with default page as it is and so i think there is no issue of loop.

Comment: composer dumpautoload

Comment: composer dumpautoload works for me. I need to execute this only for one time . Right ?

Comment: Now it seems load fast compare to previous. However i assume that page load speed of laraval is slightly low compare to codeigniter. May be due to blade template or any other reason. If it is due to blade template then can we disable it ?

Comment: I thought its working . but it is same as it is before. it takes time. When i did test it after 3 hours. Then it taking time (approx 2 seconds) on first page load.

Comment: i believe this due to your localhost , are you using homestead ?

Comment: I have setup wamp server in local pc  (WINDOWS PC)